# When you update an iOS app, what happens to the Documents folder contents?

Tags: ios, directory, documents

What happens when I update an app that has some files stored in the Documents folder? I need those files to be kept in that folder so the updated app will be able to use them. But it doesn't seem to happen. Is there anyway I can manage to save all my files?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your documents will stay where they are - unless the user deletes the app before updating (but that wouldn't be an update..).

Comment: And they will also be backed up to iTunes (tethered/WiFi) or iCloud. This is why Apple requests that you only store in /Documents data that the user created himself and you/your app can't reliably recreate by itself. Anything else will hog bandwidth/storage for backups.