# Updating an iOS app Deletes the content of Documents Folder

Tags: ios

I have a folder structures inside the Documents Folder of iOS App. I am creating folder for each date and storing data related to the date inside the particular folder. Now i released the new version and i got a feed back from the user saying that when he updated the app his datas are lost. I am storing the png files inside the folders. Is there any way that when the user updates the app these document folder structure remains same ?

Comment: See this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9311776/1437016) for infos. I'm facing the same problem as you, I just don't get it.